# How to copy the image of an imageview from another Imageview

Tags: android, image, imageview, drawable

I have two imageview button and i cant make the iv1's picture to be copied to iv2. i know how to setthe drawable image but the problem is, i want to copy the picture (Random picture) in iv1 and i want it to be copied also to iv2 when i clicked iv1. I hope you guys could help me. :(

```
    ImageView iv1,iv2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
        iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckView(iv1,iv2);




            }
        });

}
    private void CheckView( ImageView iv1,  ImageView iv2)
    {
        if (iv2.getDrawable().equals(R.drawable.a3)){

            iv2.setImageDrawable(iv1.getDrawable());
            iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.a3);


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
private void CheckView( ImageView iv1,  ImageView iv2)
{
     Bitmap bitmap1=((BitmapDrawable)iv2.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
      Bitmap bitmap2=
      ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a3))).getBitmap();
    if (bitmap1==bitmap2){

        iv2.setImageDrawable(iv1.getDrawable());
        iv1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a3));


    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work bro. I guess the problem here is the if statement.

Comment: get the bitmaps from the drawables and compare those bitmaps. See my edit.